# Detecting stopped system actor under system guardian

Tags: c#, akka.net

I' using Akka.net and Akka.Persistence version 1.3.1.

I want to give my application a little bit more fault tolerance regarding the database connection which is established by Akka.Persistence.Sql.

In case of a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (no connection, connection lost and so on) I would like to react my way. Actually the Akka.Persistence actor is stopping itself in case of an missing database connection while initialization.

```
#SqlSnapshotStore.cs

private bool WaitingForInitialization(object message)
{
  return message.Match().With<SqlSnapshotStore.Initialized>((Action<SqlSnapshotStore.Initialized>) (_ =>
  {
    this.UnbecomeStacked();
    this.Stash.UnstashAll();
  })).With<Failure>((Action<Failure>) (failure =>
  {
    this.Log.Error(failure.Exception, "Error during snapshot store initialization", new object[0]);
    ActorBase.Context.Stop(this.Self);
  })).Default((Action<object>) (_ => this.Stash.Stash())).WasHandled;
}
```

The actor is placed under the system guardian ( [akka://myActorSystem/system/akka.persistence.journal.sql-server#123456] ), so I have no chance to monitor it like others using .watch(IActorRef).

I want to restart my system gracefully in case of a stopped akka.persistence.journal.sql-server or akka.persistence.snapshot.sql-server actor. Do you have any idea how to handle that problem?

Thanks in advance,

Richi

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve `IActorRef` for event journal or snapshot store:

```
var persistence = Persistence.Instance.Apply(actorSystem);
var journalRef = persistence.JournalFor(null); // default journal
var journalRef2 = persistence.JournalFor("akka.persistence.journal.sql-server");
var snapshotStore = persistence.SnapshotStoreFor(null); // default snapshot store
var snapshotStore2 = persistence.SnapshotStoreFor("akka.persistence.snapshot.sql-server");
```

However most of the journal actors are using circuit breaker pattern with an exponential back-off when trying to execute action on the underlying data store.